# Why was this question about a shim for a pcb migrated to photo.se?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

This question [Use Paper as Shim for Circuit Board in 3V device](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/264918/use-paper-as-shim-for-circuit-board-in-3v-device) got migrated to [http://photo.stackexchange.com](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83915/use-paper-as-shim-for-circuit-board-in-3v-device) from your site.

While there's always debate about where a question belongs, especially if it touches on multiple subjects, I think it's clear that this question is not related to photography, just because the device is used in that field.

Did this one get migrated by accident? Can you take it back? Do you want it back? Do we have to push it back or can you … pull?

Comment: What the...?  It's baaaack.  Did 5 users really vote to re-open this mess?  I just voted to close.  It could possibly be a electrical engineering question, but in its current form it definitely isn't and doesn't belong here.  Everybody seemed to agree it was crap, but yet it's back and open.  Please help by voting to close and dispensing with this mess before we get more of the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everybody needs to put aside their "crap question" biases for a minute. There is nothing there that says "migrate me to Photography". We have a winner for Dumb Migration of the Month.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on photography.SE too, but only saw this question just now by reference from here.

That is a crappy question.  I just downvoted and voted to close it on Photograpy.SE.  If it came back here, I'd probably do the same.  Put another way, it doesn't belong anywhere, so it doesn't really matter where it gets closed.

The first problem with that question is that there is way too much hand waving.  I couldn't get a reliable mental picture of what exactly this "shim" is, why, where, how you are using it, etc.  That really should have been obvious.

A picture or maybe a diagram *might* have helped initially, but now that you posted what you did first, I just want to dispense with it as expediently as possible.

Even if you added a picture and a better explanation, I wouldn't vote to reopen.  This site isn't a contest to see how crappy a question you can get away with.  If you can't be bothered to think carefully enough about the context of those you want answers from, then express things clearly in terms relevant to them, we don't want you here.  Go away.  Shape up or ship out.

Allowing you to first post crap, then have you grudgingly fix just enough for the question to not be close-worthy noises up the site.  It also teaches you and others that making a mess first works.  Bad lesson.  Better to ruthlessly close and make the asker feel thrown out, not just turned down.

Comment: "*it doesn't belong anywhere*" I think it belongs here thematically. Much more so than it belongs to [photo.se]. Your answer is not really answering this meta question. It's just a rant. You know, I also think the question is crap. That's not the point at all.

Comment: @Mag: When a question is crap, all else is irrelevant.  So yes, that is the point.

Comment: If *all else is irrelevant*, then why not migrate it to [ell.se] instead or maybe [gaming.se]? Sorry, you argument doesn't make much sense. If you think a question is crap (and it is crap), it should not be migrated to an arbitrary other site of the network.

Comment: @Mag: Migrate it to BasketWeaving.SE for all I care.  I'm just not going to get worked up about how properly or not bad questions get treated.

Comment: If you care so little, why bother answering then? If this site starts exporting toxic questions then I think this is something to get worked up about.

Comment: If you don't know what a shim is, pick up a dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

I read that question as a use/repair of some sort of photographiccy thingy.
As such it's off-topic here and should rightfully have been closed.
As for migration - I would probably have erred on the side of SE's policy of "don't migrate crap".

Comment: It was not a repair question...

Answer (score -1):

This question is not about electronics design: it's about electronics use.  As such, it's *off-topic* for EE.SE .  From here, I have two (2) options:

- Close it as *Off-topic → use*
- Find a better home for it and migrate it *Off-topic → belogs on another stack*

---

> Did this one get migrated by accident?

Intentionally, not by accident.

> Do you want it back?

Nope.  The question shouldn't have been posted to EE.SE in the first place.

> Can you take it back?  Do we have to push it back or can you … pull?

I can't pull.  Once the question is migrate it's in the custody of the destination stack.

Comment: photo.se is clearly not a better home for the question. **Do not abuse migration to get rid of unwanted questions!**

Comment: Calling isolation and heat dissipation not a part of electronics design but "electronics use" is totally ridiculous.

Comment: The O.P. did mention neither *isolation* nor *heat dissipation*.  Importantly, the O.P. is not designing an electronic device: he's using one.

Comment: I'm not reading anything into "*will it start a fire?*" and "*It's touching the backs of lots of the board components.*" at all.

Comment: The question doesn't have a photo to illustrate his concerns.  Most of us don't have the same device that he's got, so we can't visualize what he's talking about.  The question in *unclear* in addition to being *off-topic*.

Comment: Then ask for clarification in a comment, down-/closevote accordingly, etc.  but please don't robo-migrate the question just because the word photography is mentioned in it.

Comment: @Mag: No, I'm going to close and/or downvote first, *then*, maybe, if I feel like it, if the question wasn't too bad, I might ask for more information or tell you why it was closed.  Note that we don't owe you any of that.  If you can't post good questions without needing diapering and burping, then you're not worth having here.

Comment: I've read the question twice, and still fail to see where the "migrate it to Photography" idea came from...

Comment: From "*... a PocketWizard Plus X for you **photographers** out there ...* [emphasis mine, N.A.]", @Matt.